# TypeScript: dynamic union type derived from an object value

Tags: typescript, union-types

I want to derive a union type from a table-like input object. I've succeed with a working solution but I suppose there should be shorter / more straightforward way. Here's the input object:

```
const _COLUMNS = {
  "id": {sortable: true}, // more metadata in real code
  "@fullname": {sortable: true},
  "@profiles": {sortable: false},
  "created_at": {sortable: false},
  ...
} as const
```

And here's my solution:

```
type Column = keyof (typeof _COLUMNS)

// ---
type FindSortable<K extends string, T extends {sortable : boolean}> = T extends {sortable : true} ? K : never

type _Sortable = {
  [K in Column] : MakeSortable<K, typeof _COLUMNS[K]>
}

type Sortable = _Sortable[keyof _Sortable] // "id" | "@fullname"
type Order = `${Sortable}:${"asc" | "desc"}` // "id:asc" | "id:desc" | ...
//---
```

Is there a way to define the above dynamic `Sortable` type without a middleman `_Sortable`? Here's the repeating structure:

```
type Sortable = 
  | FindSortable<"id", typeof _COLUMNS["id"]>
  | FindSortable<"@fullname", typeof _COLUMNS["@fullname"]>
  ...
  | FindSortable<K, typeof _COLUMNS[K]> ??
```

Or in math-like notation:

```
type Sortable = FindSortable<K, typeof _COLUMNS[K]> ∀ K in Column ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can immediately [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the property values of the mapped type from `_Sortable` instead of assigning it to a new type alias:

```
type Sortable = {
  [K in Column]: FindSortable<K, typeof _COLUMNS[K]>
}[Column]
```

I'm not sure why it matters that you eliminate `_Sortable`, but if you don't want to define `FindSortable` or even `Column` you could do everything in a single type alias:

```
type Sortable = typeof _COLUMNS extends infer C ?
  keyof C extends infer K ?
  K extends keyof C ?
  C[K] extends { sortable: true } ?
  K : never : never : never : never;

// type Sortable = "id" | "@fullname"
```

but that's just silly .

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+gYQPIBkCqBZAcgZRgXhgG8AoGGAIgEsATCgLmJghACcoBDAIwBsBTRlFYBXPjAC+AGhgB6GTAC2bMQr6caHTjCpgYrPhx4xQNPmUoABAGbCePMB1UMmLdt36CRYqeYoWADqwgVlT8EM5EzGycvAIwVoYQ3pK+wPqafDRwmhFRbrGMCTxJEinkcjAAdNUk4jAcEMbg0CQkUACe-mIIIDzCCrqEANZ87cEwABQdXeOIqJi4AJStFQC0622dYgBiOjQ40e58ADwA0jB8AB5QfGA0jdCsOgDm0gAqF9e39y6HBTBcEC9Ay6cQAPgI5g+Vxud0akVcMQ8MCEogkMAA-DBzowwHwAG58VitaZiA75fgEYjmADa5x0MB6fQGAF1GLs7uSkSdTtJSbNkOhsDg6SywbUaUz+mAWSStjAuUcAExU-lWeCChZ4GHfRo6KxExmY8wjMbqhCfWE-fWG84Y8znHVwmCm8YW+3kBCiy2634UuKo7zG8g4mB4wmsGC4gmG6MRqNhmOsADcK3kpIVf34KsI1DoMAAPpYbHYHE5WpsujAkKxTJHCAADAAkREVsXE9BbFAawAohcopggvfEDdk8jz9B7faLE8Hvf71UqJDk61WQA)